# Rabbitmq expose to the world

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I want to know if is there a way to make my rabbitmq public, so that i can interact with him in remote computers.

In localhost, the rabbitmq is open in port 15672, but not 5672.
I've open port 15672 in firewall, and try to interact it with my public id, but it failed.

Is there a way to make my rabbitmq public for remote computers?
Maybe there's a problem with port 5672 that i need to fix?
guidance will be great.

I'm using windows 7 64-bit.

Thank you.

Comment: Rabbitmq usues `5672` as broker port and `15672`. 
Maybe it is a firewall problem. Try to use  `telnet yourserver 5672` to see if the port is opened

Comment: I haven't used rabbitmq so far, but have you looked at your configuration on which networkinterface/IP it is accepting connections from? If it is limited to the loopback-device, you can configure your firewall as much as you want, it wont help. It is a little bit like telling someone to only answer calls when the green phone rings, but not the red one.

Comment: I hope this is for testing and not for production...

Comment: Not for production nor testing just learning